# how to fit the size of the imageview to it`s father view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, imageview

I have a UIView and I want to add an image as it`s subview ( [view addSubview:imageView]). I want to know how to set the size of the imageView to fit the size of the UIView (By programming) . By default, the image is too large to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

When a child is working within the view of it's parent, it should use the parent's bounds and not the parent's frame.

```
imageView.frame = self.bounds.frame
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the frame of image view equals to view, like -

```
imageView.frame = self.view.frame
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.origin.x, self.view.origin.y, elf.view.bounds..size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```